# How to trigger recomputation of computed property by DOM manipulation

Tags: ractivejs

In my test suite I'd like to confirm the effect of entering a character into a text input field. It should result in the change of a computed value.

It is, in fact, working correctly and recomputing when I type characters into the text field.

If I set the text field using

```
$('#my_input_field').val("F")
```

the computed value is not changed. Nor does it change if I trigger a keydown or keyup event on the input element. How can the property recomputation be triggered programmatically through DOM manipulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ractive.updateModel(keypath)` to force two-way bindings to update:

```
<input value='{{value}}'/>
```

```
ractive.find('input').value = 'newValue';
ractive.updateModel('value'); // or just `ractive.updateModel()`
console.log( ractive.get( 'value' ) ); // 'newValue'
```

If you want to cause the update by triggering artificial DOM events, use the `change` event, because that's what the two-way binding is listening for (rather than `keydown` and friends). It has to be a native DOM event, not a jQuery event (which uses a different mechanism) – the Ractive test suite uses [simulant](https://github.com/rich-harris/simulant) to make this a bit less of a hassle.

---

Comment: Most helpful, as always Rich Harris. Thank you very much.